# AmChart.makeChart properties not having an effect

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I am using the makeChart method of AmCharts to construct a line chart, see the jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Lw7ahxwh/

The problem I am having is that some of the properties are not changing the chart, whereas others of the same field are:

```
        graphs: [
          {
              id: "sensordata1",
              title: "Sensor 1",
              valueField: "sensor5",
              type: "line",
              linethickness: 100,    //the linethickness does not change
              linecolor: "#000000"   //the linecolor does not change
          },
```

All parameters other than `linethickness` and `linecolor` work.

```
        chartScrollbar: {
            updateOnReleaseOnly: true,
            graph: "sensordata1",
            position: "bottom", //cannot get the scrollbar to the bottom
            height: 100         //the scrollbar does not change height with this number
        },
```

The `ChartScrollbar` `graph` and `updateOnReleaseOnly` work, but `position` and `height` appear ignored.

There are a few other examples in the jsfiddle - see the comments within the code. Any help would be much appreciated - feel free to Fork the jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All config parameters in amCharts are case-sensitive and should be in camelCase. So you should change `linethickness` and `linecolor` to `lineThickness` and `lineColor` respectively.

Here's your updated fiddle as per above:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lw7ahxwh/3/

I also noticed you have trailing comma (a comma after the last element in the array) in some cases. (in `graphs` and `chartCursor`) Trailing comma is usually handled by modern browsers, but may and will produce a syntax error on legacy ones, like IE7.

The above link, has that fixed as well.